# Regex: select string containing 2 specific words

Tags: r

I am trying to construct a regex expression in R as part of pivot_longer(cols = matches()
to select columns that start with drink and end with day1.

e.g.
drink_type_1_day1
drink_vol_1_day1
drink_type_1_day2
drink_vol_1_day2

currently I have ^drink
however I can't combine it with $day1

aim would be to extract
drink_type_1_day1
drink_vol_1_day1

Comment: What does your code currently look like? You should be able to use `^drink.*day1$` (The `$` anchor should be at the end and `.*` means match anything).

Comment: Cheers. The expression works (https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the regex pattern would be:

```
"^drink\\w+day1$"
```

Answer (score 1):

In dplyr, besides the regex with the "begin" special character (`^`) and "end" special character (`$`), we can also combine multiple tidyselect statements, like `starts_with` and `ends_with`. All the following are equal:

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Sepal') & ends_with('Length'))

iris %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = matches('^Sepal.*Length$'))

iris %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = Sepal.Length)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 150 × 6
   Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species name         value
         <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <chr>        <dbl>
 1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa  Sepal.Length   5.1
 2         3            1.4         0.2 setosa  Sepal.Length   4.9
 3         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa  Sepal.Length   4.7
 4         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa  Sepal.Length   4.6
 5         3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa  Sepal.Length   5  
 6         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa  Sepal.Length   5.4
 7         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa  Sepal.Length   4.6
 8         3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa  Sepal.Length   5  
 9         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa  Sepal.Length   4.4
10         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa  Sepal.Length   4.9
# ℹ 140 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a tidyverse answer. Useful for a consistent approach